# How to use NetworkReachabilityManager in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, reachability, network-connection

I want functionality similar to `AFNetworking` in Objective-C with Alamofire NetworkReachabilityManager in Swift:

```
//Reachability detection
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN: {
            [self LoadNoInternetView:NO];
            break;
        }
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi: {
            [self LoadNoInternetView:NO];
            break;
        }
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable: {
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}];
```

I am currently using the listener to know the status changes with network

```
let net = NetworkReachabilityManager()
net?.startListening()
```

Can someone describe how to support those use cases?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer myself i.e by just writing a listener with closure as mentioned below:

```
let net = NetworkReachabilityManager()

net?.listener = { status in
    if net?.isReachable ?? false {

    switch status {

    case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
        print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

    case .reachable(.wwan):
        print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

    case .notReachable:
        print("The network is not reachable")

    case .unknown :
        print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

    }
}

net?.startListening()
```

Comment: can you explain your answer further more? I mean exactly where do I have to add this code should I create the separate structure for this code?

Answer (score 39):

**NetworkManager Class**

```
class NetworkManager {

//shared instance
static let shared = NetworkManager()

let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")

func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {

    reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
        switch status {

            case .notReachable:
                print("The network is not reachable")

            case .unknown :
                print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

            case .reachable(.wwan):
                print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

            }
        }

        // start listening
        reachabilityManager?.startListening()
   }
}
```

**Start Network Reachability Observer**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // add network reachability observer on app start
        NetworkManager.shared.startNetworkReachabilityObserver()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: ```reachabilityManager?.startListening()```  you place at wrong place bro. :D

Comment: I tried this but the listener gets called once when you turn off the wifi and not getting called back again when you turn it on. I tried holding a reference to it as I read in several places. For instance, I tried with a singleton but still experiencing this.

Comment: @JesusAdolfoRodriguez - I had the exact same problem testing my app in the simulator, but when I installed my app on a device, the reachability manager worked as written here.

Comment: we found that using reachability against a host would give false unreachable under certain enterprise networks with proxy servers. I dont know exactly as the network at the time was setup by a third party, We decided simply to just start it with no host.

Answer (score 16):

Here's my implementation.  I use it in a singleton.  Remember to hold on to the reachability manager reference.

```
let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

func listenForReachability() {
    self.reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
        print("Network Status Changed: \(status)")
        switch status {
        case .NotReachable:
            //Show error state
        case .Reachable(_), .Unknown:
            //Hide error state
        }
    }

    self.reachabilityManager?.startListening()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using a singleton is working as I long as you keep a reference of reachabilityManager

```
class NetworkStatus {
static let sharedInstance = NetworkStatus()

private init() {}

let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
    reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in

        switch status {

        case .notReachable:
            print("The network is not reachable")

        case .unknown :
            print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

        case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
            print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

        case .reachable(.wwan):
            print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

        }
    }
    reachabilityManager?.startListening()
}
```

So you can use it like this anywhere in your app:

```
let networkStatus = NetworkStatus.sharedInstance

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    networkStatus.startNetworkReachabilityObserver()
}
```

You will be notified of any change in your network status. 
Just for icing on the cake [this](https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner) is a very good animation to show on your internet connection loss.

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 5**

**NetworkState Structure**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct NetworkState {

    var isInternetAvailable:Bool
    {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

**Use: -**

```
  if (NetworkState().isInternetAvailable) {
        // Your code here
   }
```

Comment: Does this mean we no longer have to use `reachabilityManager?.listener` since it gives an error `Value of type 'NetworkReachabilityManager' has no member 'listener'`

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5:
No need for listener object . Just we need to call the closure :

```
struct Network {

    let manager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager()

    func state() {
        manager?.startListening { status in
            switch status {
            case .notReachable :
                print("not reachable")
            case .reachable(.cellular) :
                print("cellular")
            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi) :
                print("ethernetOrWiFi")
            default :
                print("unknown")
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

You can start using this function  like :

```
Network().state()
```

Answer (score 3):

Apple says to use a struct instead of a class when you can. So here's my version of @rmooney and @Ammad 's answers, but using a struct instead of a class.  Additionally, instead of using a method or function, I am using a computed property and I got that idea from this Medium [post](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/checking-internet-connection-in-swift-3-1-using-alamofire-58ae45719f5) by @Abhimuralidharan.  I'm just putting both the idea of using a struct instead of a class (so you don't have to have a singleton) and using a computed property instead of a method call together in one solution.

Here's the struct NetworkState:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct NetworkState {

    var isConnected: Bool {
        // isReachable checks for wwan, ethernet, and wifi, if
        // you only want 1 or 2 of these, the change the .isReachable
        // at the end to one of the other options.
        return NetworkReachabilityManager(host: www.apple.com)!.isReachable
    }
}
```

Here is how you use it in any of your code:

```
if NetworkState().isConnected {
    // do your is Connected stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To create **NetworkManager Class** as follows (*For SWIFT 5*)

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class NetworkManager {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")
    func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
        reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: { status in

            switch status {
                            case .notReachable:
                                print("The network is not reachable")
                            case .unknown :
                                print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
                            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                                print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
                            case .reachable(.cellular):
                                print("The network is reachable over the cellular connection")
                      }
        })
    }
}
```

And the usage will be like

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // add network reachability observer on app start
        NetworkManager.shared.startNetworkReachabilityObserver()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: - Alamofire (4.9.1): startListening is just returning bool

Comment: that's because this code is for compatible with Alamofire 5 which changed this part of the API

Answer (score 2):

**Alamofire 5 and above**

```
import Alamofire

// MARK: NetworkReachability

final class NetworkReachability {
    
    static let shared = NetworkReachability()

    private let reachability = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")!

    typealias NetworkReachabilityStatus = NetworkReachabilityManager.NetworkReachabilityStatus

    private init() {}
    
    /// Start observing reachability changes
    func startListening() {
        reachability.startListening { [weak self] status in
            switch status {
            case .notReachable:
                self?.updateReachabilityStatus(.notReachable)
            case .reachable(let connection):
                self?.updateReachabilityStatus(.reachable(connection))
            case .unknown:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Stop observing reachability changes
    func stopListening() {
        reachability.stopListening()
    }
    
    
    /// Updated ReachabilityStatus status based on connectivity status
    ///
    /// - Parameter status: `NetworkReachabilityStatus` enum containing reachability status
    private func updateReachabilityStatus(_ status: NetworkReachabilityStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notReachable:
            print("Internet not available")
        case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi), .reachable(.cellular):
            print("Internet available")
        case .unknown:
            break
        }
    }

    /// returns current reachability status
    var isReachable: Bool {
        return reachability.isReachable
    }

    /// returns if connected via cellular
    var isConnectedViaCellular: Bool {
        return reachability.isReachableOnCellular
    }

    /// returns if connected via cellular
    var isConnectedViaWiFi: Bool {
        return reachability.isReachableOnEthernetOrWiFi
    }

    deinit {
        stopListening()
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

Call `NetworkReachability.shared.startListening()` from `AppDelegate` to start listening for reachability changes

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
            
    var window: UIWindow?
           
            
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
             
        NetworkReachability.shared.startListening()
        
        // window and rootviewcontroller setup code
        
        return true
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slight Improvement in the Alamofire 5

```
class NetworkManager {

//shared instance
static let shared = NetworkManager()

let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")

func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
    
    reachabilityManager?.startListening { status in
        switch status {

        case .notReachable:
            print("The network is not reachable")

        case .unknown :
            print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

        case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
            print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

        case .reachable(.cellular):
            print("The network is reachable over the cellular connection")

        }
     }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution for swift 4* + swift 5* and Alamofire 4.5+**

> **CREATE** a `NetworkReachabilityManager` class from `Alamofire` and
>   configure the `checkNetwork()` method

```
import Alamofire

class Connectivity {   
    class func checkNetwork() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

> **USAGE**

```
switch Connectivity.checkNetwork() {
  case true:
      print("network available")
      //perform task
  case false:
      print("no network")
}
```