# Implement Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager for global use

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How to implement `Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager` for global use in an application to check network connectivity in swift?

I want to use NetworkReachabilityManager to check internet connectivity but in global way.

Comment: is the ques different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427698/how-to-use-networkreachabilitymanager-in-alamofire ?

Comment: It is related with that but not same. I want to know that how can I use that singleton object globally.

Comment: maybe keep it in app delegate or make a DataManager class singleton separately for all your data request where you keep track of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple singleton like this:

```
import Alamofire

public class NetworkManager {
    public static var sharedManager: NetworkReachabilityManager = {
        let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
        // Add additional setup for the manager
        return manager!
    }()
}
```

And you can use it through the app like:

```
NetworkManager.sharedManager
```