# WorkManager or Queue for URL Session for calling web apis in Swift to sync data only when network is available

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

Is there the concept of a WorkManager in SwiftUI like there is in Android. The use case is syncing data when there is not a reliable network. In this use case I have a Core Data database on the iPhone/iPad and updates can happen without a network connection, but I want to update the main server by calling a web api when network connectivity is available.

When a new record is created in iPhone Core Data, I want to queue up the change for when the network is available and update the local record with the results. If there is an error, I would like to save it as well. Ideally I could have some control over frequency and number of tries. I also don't want it to try if there is no network.

I also want the queued request to persist even when the app shuts down.

For example, using my iPhone I create a new record in Core Data. The phone is not connected to the network when I do, but the request is queued up, but does not try to call the web api because there is no network. I shut down the app and open it up later in a different location where there is network service. The call fails for some reason and I shut down the app again. I open the app later in an area where there is service and the web api call is tried again and succeeds.

My current API calls look like this:

```
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

    let json = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

}
```

I've done a number of searches and perhaps my terms are wrong because I have not been able to find this scenario. I am new to iOS so it's likely I'm just searching for the wrong things.

I've seen videos [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDxUqZ65fsU) on concurrency with URLSession but it seems to be an immediate request running in the background and not a the specific situation of network connectivity and persisting of the request. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931472/is-there-a-way-to-queue-api-calls-if-no-network-is-available-and-send-them-when) but it was a while ago and not answered.

Comment: Use [Background Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks) this will accomplish your requirement.