# Swift2 iOS Reachability Class and NSNotificatonCenter not receiving broadcast

Tags: ios, swift2, appdelegate, nsnotificationcenter, reachability

I have a tabBarController with 2 tabs and a `Reachability` class for the internet connection.

Inside the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching` method I have a `checkReachability` function that checks the current network connection to see if wifi is on or off and it will broadcast a `NSNotification` to the second tab in either case.

Inside the second tab there is label and inside `viewDidLoad` there are 2 observers listening  for the broadcasts. I also have 2 functions (triggered by the observers) that will change the label text based on the current network connection.

I'm using the simulator and when I toggle the wifi on/off from either the first or second tab the second tab's label text never changes.

Why is the text not changing and why are the observers not responding?

Reachability Class:
FYI I got the Reachability Class from this youtube vid and I switched it from Swift 3 to Swift 2.3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlsfXjESatg&t=532s

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration

protocol Utilities {
}

extension NSObject:Utilities{

    enum ReachabilityStatus {
        case notReachable
        case reachableViaWWAN
        case reachableViaWiFi
    }

    var currentReachabilityStatus: ReachabilityStatus {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else {
            return .notReachable
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return .notReachable
        }

        if flags.contains(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) == false{
            // The target host is not reachable.
            return .notReachable
        }
        else if flags.contains(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) == true{
            // WWAN connections are OK if the calling application is using the CFNetwork APIs.
            return .reachableViaWWAN
        }

        else if flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired) == false {
            // If the target host is reachable and no connection is required then we'll assume that you're on Wi-Fi...
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        }
        else if (flags.contains(.ConnectionOnDemand) == true || flags.contains(.ConnectionOnTraffic) == true) && flags.contains(.InterventionRequired) == false {
            // The connection is on-demand (or on-traffic) if the calling application is using the CFSocketStream or higher APIs and no [user] intervention is needed
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        }
        else {
            return .notReachable
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.checkReachability()

    return true
}
//This function is declared inside AppDelegate 
func checkReachability(){
    if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWiFi {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("wifi", object: nil)
    }else if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWWAN{
            print("WWAN.")
    }else{
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("noWifi", object: nil)
    }
}
```

Second Tab:

```
class SecondTabController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(wifiConnection), name: "wifi", object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(noConnection), name: "noWifi", object: nil)
 }

func wifiConnection(){
    self.labelTwo.text = "Wifi Connection"
 }

func noConnection(){
    self.labelTwo.text = "No Connection"
 }

deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "wifi", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "noWifi", object: nil)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting the notification only once to the notification center, namely when your application starts:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Your method `checkReachability` will post notifications:
    self.checkReachability()
    return true
}
```

However your `SecondTabController` is not yet created and thus it is not yet subscribed for receiving the notification that you send at app start. When notifications are posted, they are received *immediately* by any subscribers. Notifications "don't wait" until some subscriber is added at a later point in time.

What you probably need as a reachability manager that continues to live and posts notifications to the notification center whenever WiFi reachability changes.

You might want to use existing reachability managers, [such as Alamofire's NetworkReachabilityManager as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427698/how-to-use-networkreachabilitymanager-in-alamofire).

Comment: Bumberg Thanks for the advice and HNY ! Look at this video. He's not using a tabBar but sets the checkStatus function in didFinish (min 12:09) and has a subscriber in a another vc's viewDidLoad (albeit single vc app not tab). When he toggles wifi on/off it works fine (min 29:35). If my second tab isn't created yet, once I tap it, it is alive, at that point shouldn't toggling wifi on/off while still inside that tab work like his? I also put my same subscriber code in tabOne as it only has a label. It loads immediately at start and nothing happens there either. https://youtu.be/BlBhHgoW9wM –